Why determinant appears in $\int\frac{dx}{(a+bx)(c+dx)}=\frac1{\begin{vmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{vmatrix}}\ln\left|\frac{c+dx}{a+bx}\right|+C$?
I was evaluating $\int\dfrac{dx}{(a+bx)(c+dx)}$ and got  $\dfrac1{ad-bc}\ln\left|\dfrac{c+dx} {a+bx}\right|+C$ as the result. I'm wondering if there is any way to justify why determinant appears here.
I used partial fraction for evaluating this integral and my approach. I think it doesn't provide any hint on why it appears. Here is my approach:
$$\dfrac{1}{(bx+a)(dx+c)}=\dfrac M{bx+a}+\dfrac N{dx+c}$$
Solving system of two linear equations on $M$ and $N$ results in $M=\dfrac{b}{bc-ad}$ and $N=\dfrac{-d}{bc-ad}$. The integral is:
$$\int\dfrac{dx}{(a+bx)(c+dx)}=\dfrac1{bc-ad}\int\dfrac b{bx+a}-\dfrac{d}{dx+c}dx=\dfrac1{bc-ad}\ln\left|\dfrac{bx+a}{dx+c}\right|$$
$$=\dfrac1{\begin{vmatrix} a & b \\  c & d \end{vmatrix}}\ln\left|\dfrac{c+dx}{a+bx}\right|+C$$

Reminds me of Mobius functions.

One related observation: if $(a,b)$ is a scalar multiple of $(c,d)$, then instead of a logarithm you would get a scalar multiple of $\frac{1}{c+dx}$ plus $C$ as the integral.

"Note on Partial Fractions and Determinants" looks like it might be useful

It seems pretty clear that the determinants show up directly in solving for the coefficients in the partial fraction decomposition.

I doubt anything deep is going on here. In general if you have a difference of fractions $a/b - c/d$, the determinant shows up. I asked a similar question a while ago: 2x2 Matrices and Differences of Fractions.

Because of Cramer's Rule, when you solve a system of linear equations with symbolic coefficients the determinant of the coefficient matrix will show up.

Because of Cramer's Rule, when you solve a system of linear equations with symbolic coefficients the determinant of the coefficient matrix will show up.  Similarly if you want to write
$$ \dfrac{1}{(a + b x + c x^2)(d + ex + f x^2)} = \frac{X + xY}{a + b x + c x^2} + \frac{Z + x W}{d + e x + f x^2}$$
you end up solving the system
$$\pmatrix{ 0 & f & 0 & c\cr f & e & c & b\cr e & d & b & a\cr d & 0 & a & 0\cr} \pmatrix{X\cr Y\cr Z\cr W\cr} = \pmatrix{0\cr 0\cr 0\cr 1\cr}$$
and the solution will involve a denominator of
$ a^{2} f^{2}-a b e f -2 a c d f +a c \,e^{2}+b^{2} d f -b c d e +c^{2} d^{2}$, which is the determinant of the $4 \times 4$ coefficient matrix.

The question is about the appearance of the determinant in

$\int\frac{dx}{(a+bx)(c+dx)}=\frac1{\begin{vmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{vmatrix}}\ln\left|\frac{c+dx}{a+bx}\right|+C$

One answer begins with the derivation
$$ \frac{d}{dx} \ln \left|\frac{c+dx}{a+bx}\right| =
 \frac{d}{c+dx} - \frac{b}{a+bx} = \frac{ad-bc}{(a+bx)(c+dx)} $$
where we used the identity
$$ d(a+bx)-b(c+dx) =
 \begin{vmatrix} a+bx & b \\ c+dx & d \end{vmatrix} =
 \begin{vmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{vmatrix} = ad-bc  $$
which is a special case of the identity $\texttt{id6_3_2_3a}$ in
my "Special Algebraic Identities" collection.
The determinant is zero if and only if $\,a+bx\,$ and $\,c+dx\,$ are
linearly dependent in which case the integral is not logarithmic.
This explains why the determinant is important for the integral.
More precisely, the integrand in general has two poles except when
$\,a+bx\,$ and $\,c+dx\,$ are linearly dependent in which case the
integrand has an order two pole whose integral has a single pole.
Integrate both sides to get
$$ \ln\left|\frac{c+dx}{a+bx}\right| = \int\frac{ad-bc}{(a+bx)(c+dx)}dx + C. $$
Divide both sides by the determinant and the result follows.
Notice that, if we replace $a$ with $ay$ and $c$ with $cy$ the result
$$ \ln\left|\frac{cy+dx}{ay+bx}\right| = \int\frac{ad-bc}{(ay+bx)(cy+dx)}dx + C $$
is more symmetrical but essentially the same.

Here's one more way of looking at it.
We know the behaviour has to be very different in the special case $a:b=c:d$ viz.$$\int\frac{dx}{(a+bx)^2}=-\frac{1}{b(a+bx)}+C'.$$(I write $C'$, not $C$, for reasons that become evident if you try matching the two indefinite integrals.) So the logarithm needs to be divided by something that vanishes when $ad-bc=0$.
What's more, if we use dimensional analysis whereby $a,\,c,\,x$ have the dimensions of length while $b,\,d$ is dimensionless, we see the denominator needs to have the dimension of length, which the determinant has, thus precluding e.g. squaring it.
It takes a careful calculation to determine the coefficient $K$ in$$\int\frac{dx}{(a+bx)(c+dx)}=\frac{K}{ad-bc}\ln\left|\frac{c+dx}{a+bx}\right|+C.$$Considering the small-$x$ behaviour of an antiderivative vanishing at $x=0$,$$\frac{x}{ac}\sim\frac{K}{ad-bc}\ln\left|\frac{1+dx/c}{1+bx/a}\right|\sim\frac{K(d/c-b/a)}{ad-bc}x\implies K=1.$$
